# Save errors to a variable while reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, logging

I’m trying to read an unknown large csv file with pandas.
I came across some errors so I added the following arguments:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, engine="python", error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=True)
```

It is working good and skipping offending lines, and errors are prompted to the terminal correctly, such as:

```
Skipping line 31175: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

However, I’d like to save all errors to a variable instead of printing them.
How can I do it?

Note that I have a big program here and can't change the output of all logs from `file=sys.stdout` to something else. I need a case specific solution.

Thanks!

Comment: So do you really need to save the errors to a variable? Or are you asking how to log the errors to anywhere you want rather than just printing? For the logging part, you can look into how to redirect `stderr` (not `stdout`) to a file.

Comment: I need to both save it to a variable (I later send the errors to the user via API) and to keep them on stdout for my own use.

Answer (score 1):

use `on_bad_lines` capability instead (available in pandas 1.4+):

```
badlines_list = []
def badlines_collect (bad_line: list[str]) -> None:
        badlines_list.append(bad_line)
        return None

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, engine="python",on_bad_lines=badlines_collect)
```

Comment: At first I couldn't use it due to deprecated pandas version. After upgrading the package I wrote exactly what you suggested, except for the ```: list[str]) - > list[str]:``` (which raised an ```'type' object is not subscriptable``` error for me) and it didn't work... What is this part used for? Can I do it without this part?

Comment: @Itayst you need version 1.4 for that feature

Comment: Yeah as I said I upgraded the package, the issue is not with pandas but the syntax of the function. I'm getting error on the ```(bad_line: list[str]) -> None:``` part. How can I fix it?